# C# Server\Client using https and udp

Tags: c#, https, server, udp, client

i have a task.
Create simple multithreaded server-client in C# using https and udp. There is a question< how can i send info from client using https and recieve it using udp listening 443 port. Is it possible to do smth like that or it is no way to use https and udp in C#.

P.S. if i use Tcp Listener it works fine, but UdpClient doesn't react on messages from client on the same port.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered in it's current form, not enough details. Try showing us some relevant client and server code, might clear things up. Try using the form [mcve]

Comment: It is impossible.Close question.

Comment: nothing is impossible. it's just a question of time. this is why I was interested in seing more code. You must go third-party though. Did you look at [this library](https://github.com/CreatorDev/DTLS.Net) ?